# Azure WebApp Memory Working Set went down after upgrading to paid basic tier

Tags: azure, memory, azure-web-app-service

I have a WebApp in Azure. On the 29th of Mars, I upgraded from free (dev) tier to paid Basic1 tier.

Since then, my average Memory Working Set has dropped down tenfold.
[image: average Memory Working Set graph]

Why does my app require/consume less memory?

Comment: Free tier runs an app on the same Azure VM as other App Service apps, including apps of other customers. If other's code has some memory leak,it will increase the memory.Basic tier runs apps on dedicated Azure VMs, so there won't cause the issue.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not it because this is the graph for the Web App, not the App Service (App Services contain 0-many Web Apps). In the span of a few months, the amount of Web Apps in the same App Service fluctuated between 1 and 4 and the graph (for individual apps) stayed the same.